# DIY paint touch-up on rusted fender: paint touch-up kit includes primer, color, and clear coat

Tags: paint, paint-clearcoat

We have some rust on the fender of our 2005 car. I'd like to try to touch it up by removing the loose paint, sanding the rust off, priming, painting, and clear-coating, using one of the kits that can be bought with matching paint color.

Is there any trick to "feathering in" the paint to the adjacent good areas? Can the primer go on top of the clearcoat of the good adjacent sections?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The primer should not go over existing clear coat.

You should think of circles of increasing diameter for each layer : primer smallest, paint next and then clear...

Answer (score 0):

Paint is the least of your problems , the fender is rusted through. I am surprised to see that much rust on a 2005. Serious grind > phosphate /conversion treat > fiberglas > grind / sand > body putty > sand > begin painting. And look for more rust in other locations.

Comment: I suspect it was in an accident and sub-standard body repair was done .